# How far is Brahmaloka from our Earth?

Tags: time, lokas, earth

I mean where does Brahmaloka lie? Is there any scripture that tells it's exact location and time difference between different lokas?

Comment: The different spheres, lokas, are at different levels of vibration. The spiritual realms are not within the sensual universe. The Puranas describe them in material dimensional space as all cannot grasp the concepts of spiritual realms, but can easily understand a vast spatial distance as most think of themselves as material beings

Comment: The different spheres, lokas, are at different levels of vibration. The spiritual realms are not within the sensual universe. The Puranas describe them in material dimensional space as all cannot grasp the concepts of spiritual realms, but can easily understand a vast spatial distance as most think of themselves as material beings

Comment: "The spiritual realms are not within the sensual universe." Proving its existence is impossible then. Such a statement must then be refuted.

Comment: I had seen an image from some book, which shows all 14 Lokas and their distance in yojanas, but I can't find it now

Answer (score 5):

*A partial answer ...*

Skanda Purana says that the distance is **8 crore yojanas**.

Quoting from the book ["Essence of Skanda Purana"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana37.html):

> there was no Place like Bharat which happened to be the ‘Karmabhumi’
> or the Place where Noble Deeds were rewarded and there was no Tirtha
> like Kasi and no Bhagavan like Viswanath Linga in the Universe.’
> Having visited Satya Loka, Siva Sharma asked the Vishnu Prashads as to
> how far he would have to travel farther and the latter replied that
> from Prithvi to Surya Loka the distance was away by a lakh Yojanas
> (one Yojana is 13-16 km approx); from Prithvi to Maha Loka is one
> Crore Yojanas; from Prithvi to Jana Loka is two crore yojanas, four
> crore yojanas from Prithvi to Tapa Loka **and eight crore yojanas to Satya Loka;**
> sixteen crore yojanas to Vishnu Loka and sixteen times higher from
> Vaikuntha to Kailasa Dham; in other words, the distance from Bhu Loka
> to Kailas is a staggering figure of two arab and fifty six crore
> yojanas! From Satya Loka Siva Sharma was blessed to travel further to
> reside at Vaikuntha.

Note that [Brahmaloka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmaloka) is another name for the Satyaloka. And, for understanding the unit of measurement, Yojana, see [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yojana).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91283/discussion-on-answer-by-rickross-how-far-is-brahmaloka-from-our-earth).

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the Vishnu Purana:

> Parasara said: The sphere of the earth (or Bhúr-loka), comprehending its oceans, mountains, and rivers, extends as far as it is illuminated by the rays of the sun and moon; and to the same extent, both in diameter and circumference, the sphere of the sky (Bhuvar-loka) spreads above it (as far upwards as to the planetary sphere, or Swar-loka). **The solar orb is situated a hundred thousand yojanas from the earth; and that of the moon an equal distance from the sun. At the same interval above the moon occurs the orbit of all the lunar constellations. The planet Budha (Mercury) is two hundred thousand yojanas above the lunar mansions. Śukra (Venus) is at the same distance from Mercury. Angáraka (Mars) is as far above Venus; and the priest of the gods (Vrihaspati, or Jupiter) as far from Mars: whilst Saturn (Sani) is two hundred and fifty thousand yojanas beyond Jupiter. The sphere of the seven Rishis (Ursa Major) is a hundred thousand yojanas above Saturn; and at a similar height above the seven Rishis is Dhruva (the pole-star), the pivot or axis of the whole planetary circle. Such, Maitreya, is the elevation of the three spheres (Bhúr, Bhuvar, Swar) which form the region of the consequences of works. The region of works is here (or in the land of Bhárata). Above Dhruva, at the distance of ton million yojanas, lies the sphere of saints, or Mahar-loka, the inhabitants of which dwell in it throughout a Kalpa, or day of Brahmá. At twice that distance is situated Janaloka, where Sanandana and other pure-minded sons of Brahmá, reside. At four times the distance, between the two last, lies the Tapo-loka (the sphere of penance), inhabited by the deities called Vaibhrájas, who are unconsumable by fire. At six times the distance (a hundred and twenty millions of yojanas) is situated Satya-loka (Brahma-loka), the sphere of truth, the inhabitants of which never again know death.** (**Vishnu Purana, Book II, Chapter VII**)

Comment: Why did you delete the answer?

Comment: So the answer is 120 million yojanas, right?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Idk. Not sure if that calculation is correct.

Comment: A yojana is about 12-15 km. Thusly the distance is 1440 million km - 1800 million km.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. The extent to which the rays of the sun and the moon shine and illuminate is the size of the earth. It is called Bhūloka.
>
> 2-3. The sun’s sphere is situated a hundred thousand Yojanas from the
> earth. The moon is situated thousands of Yojanas from this earth and a
> hundred thousand Yojanas from the sun.
>
> 4. The spheres of the planets are entirely situated above the moon along with the stars about ten thousand Yojanas one above the other.
> 5. Budha (Mercury); above that is Kāvya (Venus): above that is the sphere of Bhauma (Mars). Bṛhaspati (Jupiter) is above that and
>    Śanaiścara (Saturn) is above that.
> 6. The sphere of the seven sages (The Ursa Major) is situated a hundred thousand Yojanas above it. The Pole Star (Dhruva) is situated
>    a hundred thousand Yojanas above the sages.
> 7. The Pole star is the prop of the circle of luminary bodies.[1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226579.html) The Bhuvarloka and Svarloka are above the earth but beneath the Pole star.
> 8. A crore Yojanas above the Pole star is the Maharloka where the seven sons of Brahmā are stationed. They live even during the time of
>    Kalpa.
> 9. The seven sons are—Sanaka, Sananda, Sanātana, Kapila, Āsuri, Voḍhu and Pañcaśikha.
> 10. Above that is stationed Śukra (Venus) at a distance of two hundred thousand Yojanas. Two hundred thousand Yojanas below it is stationed
>     Budha (Mercury) the son of the moon.
> 11. O sage, Bhauma (Mars) is stationed two hundred thousand Yojanas above it. Bṛhaspati (Jupiter) is stationed two hundred thousand
>     Yojanas above it.
> 12. Two hundred thousand Yojanas above Jupiter, Saturn is stationed. These are the seven planets that stay in their respective zodiacs.
> 13. The seven sages (Ursa Major) are stationed eleven hundred thousand Yojanas above the planet Saturn. The Dhruva star is said to be
>     stationed fourteen hundred thousand Yojanas above the great star.
> 14. **Sixty-three hundred thousand Yojanas from Janaloka is stationed the Tapoloka**  the gods called Vairājas stay. They are free from
>     burning sensation.
>
> 15-16. **Eighty four thousand Yojanas from Tapoloka is stationed the
> Satyaloka. It is known as Brahmaloka** where the pure-minded, perfectly
> wise Brahmacārins engaged in truthful virtue stay. Men who go there
> from the earth also stay there.

> [Shiva Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226579.html)